# Why MyModel.all works in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, methods

i don't understand this little thing:

Suppose, we have "Condition" model

```
class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Why Condition.all works ?

```
Condition.all.each { |p| do_something }
```

This syntax tells us, that we have "Condition" class-object instanciated somewhere ?

Or is it some convention over configuration case ?

I asking this, because i want to override Condition.all method to return Conditions, sorted by "created_at" field value ?

I don't need to use sort method in place, i want to insert Conditions to, because in the entire project i need only one sorting

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Person.all` is just an alias for `Person.find(:all)` (see the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002266)).

`all`, like `find`, is a class method on `ActiveRecord::Base` so doesn't require an instance in order to be called.

**Update**

To override a class method you need to remember the `self.` prefix. e.g. you can override `all` like this:

```
class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all(*args)
    # overridden implementation here
  end
end
```

If you aren't clear on instance methods vs. class methods read [this blog post](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) which is a good summary,

However, if you just want to specify a default ordering you *don't need to do this*. You can just use [default_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002313):

```
class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'created_at'
end
```

Comment: I chnaged Person to Condition to better reflect, what i added in my post right now.

But, regards ".all" - why we don't write "Conditions::all". Is Condition - is already instantiated class object ?

Comment: OK, when it does't require an instance in order to be called, why we call "all" as with instance ? Why not "::all" ?

Comment: Condition *is* an instance. It's an instance of a Class object. But don't get too tied up with that distinction, just understand that you can have class-level methods which are separate to instance-level methods

Comment: And yes, you *can* call Condition::all and it should work exactly the same